# Смена оконной конфигурации в emacs

Tags: emacs

Как в `emacs` переключаться и сохранять оконные настройки? Например в одной конфигурации мне нужны два окна разделенные по вертикали, во второй два окна разделенные по горизонтали, в третьей одно окно. Как сохранять эти состояния?

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/39564/) есть тема с оконными режимами(**14 пункт**), но у меня не получилось установить. Указал т.к. на русском и узнал много других полезностей, мб у кого-то умнее получится поставить.

[Здесь](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/easily-manage-emacs-workspaces-with-eyebrowse/) на английском, и то что я смог установить)

Answer (score 0):

А не проще пользоваться горячими клавишами C-x 2 и C-x 3 ?
В любом случае вам нужно будет загружать в каждое окошко свой контент.
Лучше разделять экран комбинацией клавиш C-x 2 или C-x 3 и переходить между окнами с помощью C-x o, а когда не нужно - закрывать окна с помощью C-x 0 или делать активным только одно с помощью C-x 1.
Далее - вставьте в .emacs следующие строки:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<left>") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<right>") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<down>") 'shrink-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "S-C-<up>") 'enlarge-window)
```

Это позволит вам управлять размерами окон при нажатии Shift+Ctrl+клавиш-стрелок
Попробуйте, это даже удобнее.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий. По правилам форума его снесет модератор. Чтобы этого не произошло, в Ваш рейтинг вырос, есть смысл добавить подробностей.

Comment: Развернул другой вариант решения вопроса. Так подойдёт?

Comment: Посмотрим, что решит сообщество :)

Comment: Надеюсь что ничего плохого не произойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

В emacs окна находятся внутри фрейма, дальше главное окно, затем его потомки.
Если не убивать фрейм то можно:

```
;; Захватить конфигурацию окон текущего фрейма
;; получается объект конфигурации окон фрейма
(setq crntFrm (current-window-configuration))
;; Когда потребуется восстановить конфигурацию окон фрейма
(set-window-configuration crntFrm)
```

В вашем случае, если использовать такую методику, можно сохранить три таких объекта конфигурации окон фрейма и использовать когда потребуется